# What could have caused all my Infragistics jQuery grids to break on a new dev machine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, infragistics

I have an MVC4 app that uses several Infragistics jQuery igGrid widgets. Up until Wednesday morning, this app was working very nicely. I then backed up the project, and restored it on a new machine. I have also re-installed the while Infragistics jQuery suite, although this shouldn't be necessary, as there are no GAC dependencies.

Now, on any of the grids in my app, I get an "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." exception when the grid tries to render, on the line of Razor markup that defines the grid. The stack trace is:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.DataBindInternal()
at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.DataBind()
at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.Grid`1.DataBind()
at ASP._Page_Areas_Author_Views_Course_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Development\Educ8\Educ8.Mvc\Areas\Author\Views\Course\Index.cshtml:line 16
```

This is common to every grid in the application, and isn't because the data source has changed and a column is missing or something. An example grid definition is:

```
<section class="index">
    @{
        var grid = Html.Infragistics().Grid(Model.Items.AsQueryable())
            .ID("indexGrid")
            .AutoGenerateColumns(false)
            .PrimaryKey("Id")
            .Height(Model.GridHeight)
            .Columns(col =>
                         {
                             col.For(m => m.Id).HeaderText("Id").Hidden(true);
                         }).DataBind();
    }
    @grid.Render()
</section>
```

Here I removed all columns except for Id, which I have confirmed is present in the data source.

**MORE:**
Going back through my Git commits, I found this issue arose when I encrypted my connection strings in web.config. The encryption code adds the `configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"` attribute to the `connectionStrings` section. The editor complains that this attribute is not allowed, so I added the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"` attribute to the `configuration` section. It is the presence of this last attribute that triggers the fault with the grid.

Comment: since the jQuery grid is client side only the connection string in the web.config will not have a direct impact on the grid.  Have you compared the raw data that is sent to the client both before and after the change?

Answer (score 1):

You say

```
`I then backed up the project, and restored it on a new machine.`
```

But, as far as I know, the MachineKey value, used to encrypt and decrypt the cipher values, is specific to the original machine.  Therefore, when moving your code from one machine to another, the MachineKey is different and you can't decrypt the config file.  I think you need to re-encrypt the connection string on the new machine.  This will use the local encryption key.

Perhaps [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18558/Encrypting-windows-application-connection-strings) could be of help.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, you make a very valid point, and point to a good read, but I only added the encryption after being on the new machine.

Comment: I was thinking to something that affected 'globally' your binding process on the grids. And, I still think that should be something global like, as an example, the datasource configuration, or somethiong external to the application like IIS configuration/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the Items collection is empty.

Try to use the `Model.Items` object as a grid data source instead of the `Model.Items.AsQueryable()`.

Comment: No, I checked that, thanks. If Items is empty, AsQueryable returns an empty set. See my edits for more of the mystery.